# Long to wide format using dcast in r

Tags: r, data.table, dcast, long-format-data, wide-format-data

can anyone help me figure out the code for transforming the following data in long format (Figure 1) to wide format (Figure 2)? I would like to use the wide format to make a heatmap. Thank you so much.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

I've tried

```
dat_wide <- dcast(dat1, 
                  id1+id2 ~ grade + year + category,
                  value.var = c("%level1", "%level2"))
```

Then an error message showed up saying that:
! Can't extract column with `value.var`.
✖ Subscript `value.var` must be size 1, not 2.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here would be calling the `dcast` function i.e. `dcast` is available in `data.table` and `reshape2` packages.  If the data is `data.table`, it calls the `data.table::dcast` instead of the `reshape2::dcast`, but if it is a data.frame, it may call `reshape2::dcast` (assuming both are loaded).  With `data.table::dcast`,

> value.var - ..., Cast multiple value.var columns simultaneously by passing their names as a character vector.

whereas in `?reshape2::dcast`

> value.var - name of column which stores values, see guess_value for default strategies to figure this out.
> i.e. it can take only a single column in `value.var`

-testing

```
> reshape2::dcast(dat1, 
                   id1+id2  ~ grade + year + category,
                   value.var = c("%level1", "%level2"))
Error in if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

whereas

```
dcast(as.data.table(dat1), 
                    id1+id2  ~ grade + year + category,
                    value.var = c("%level1", "%level2"))
Key: <id1, id2>
     id1   id2 %level1_3_2016_A %level1_3_2016_B %level1_3_2017_A %level1_3_2017_B %level2_3_2016_A %level2_3_2016_B %level2_3_2017_A %level2_3_2017_B
   <num> <num>            <num>            <num>            <num>            <num>            <num>            <num>            <num>            <num>
1:     1   101               58               56               57               53               33               20               34               19
2:     2   102               54               49               58               43               32               19               32               20
```

#### data

```
dat1 <- structure(list(id1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), id2 = c(101, 
101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102), grade = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3), year = c(2016, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2016, 
2017), category = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
    `%level1` = c(58, 57, 56, 53, 54, 58, 49, 43), `%level2` = c(33, 
    34, 20, 19, 32, 32, 19, 20)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you so much for pointing out the difference between `reshape2::dcast` and `data.table::dcast`! The code works pretty well. 

Comment: please accept the answer if it answers your question